# Run ".jar" through shell

Tags: java, android, shell, root, busybox

I am making an android application that aims to run a .jar file that's a java7 based console application. Could someone direct me on a way I can run this file with a shell command within my application's code?

Comment: ... I'm confused. "via shell" - that makes it sound like you're running it through another app. However, you say you're *developing* an app... so what do you mean? Do you want to call the .jar via your app?

Comment: Yeah exactly I want to run the .jar via my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Android doesn't come with a Java 7 VM. The Dalvik VM it uses is not compatible.

Comment: Is there a virtual machine library or something?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean just opening a console and running the jar? If yes, the command goes like:

```
java -jar <my jar file>
```

Can you please be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying is to run the jar from the command line (terminal) then just use

```
 java -jar <jarfile>
```

If you are trying to run a class that is inside the jar, then just make sure the jar is in the classpath and use the class directly.